# Custom hasMany relationship query with select()

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Each company on my app can store its own events.

A company and its events are related though the following `hasMany` relationship:

```
/**
 * The events that belong to the company.
 */
public function events()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Event');
}
```

To list a company's events, I use:

```
Auth::user()->company->events
```

Since each event stores, a lot of data that I don't need when I query the `hasMany`, I would like to customize the relationship to only select the `id` and `name` columns instead of the whole row.

My `hasMany` relationship query would be something like

```
DB::table('events')->where('company_id', Auth::id())->select('id', 'name')->get();
```

How do I take the collection returned from this result and use it as the query for my `hasMany` relationship, which will then correctly return a collection of event instances?

Comment: Show us your `events` method code from the company Model please I would suggest adding the `->select('id', 'name')` part inside the relationship method.

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki I have edited my question to include the `events` method's code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the filter inside your `events` method like :

```
public function events()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Event')->select('id', 'company_id', 'name');
}
```

Then call it like:

```
Auth::user()->company->events
```

*Important update: 'company_id' is necessary for company->events link, otherwise 'events' relationship always returns empty array*

Answer (score 0):

How about

`Auth::user()->company()->with('events:id,name')->get();`

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

Go to Eager Loading Specific Columns